# I was unable to combine 2 query_set of same model without apply ordering in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I was working on a project and I came across a problem. I need a query_set which should have ordering according to created date but there are some items in the query_set which I need to place at the end of the query_set at all times.

I don't need to apply ordering for those items. Those items should be always at the end of the query_set

Here is my model

```
class Bookings(model.Model):
    booking_title = models.CharField('Booking title', max_length=125, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='request_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    practice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=[1, 2], default=1)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my query_set

```
query_set = Bookings.objects.filter(status=1)
```

Here is my solution (*Which is don't work*)

```
query_set_practice = query_set.filter(practice=True)
query_set_normal = query_set.filter(practice=False).order_by('created_date')
query_set = query_set_normal | query_set_practice
```

I need normal bookings first and practice bookings. The normal bookings should be in the order (*last should be first*).

**I need an optimized solution without adding any loops and multiple query_set creations.**

**Please help me.**

Comment: Hi when you say it does not work, you mean that the solution does not produce the intended result or that is innefecient? Thanks

Comment: the solution does not produce the intended result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query_set = query_set.order_by('practice', '-created_date)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it will not work properly. The practice bookings will not get placed at the end. it will get placed randomly. It will not work if I used query_set.distinct()

Comment: i have tried this on my project and it provides the following output:
```users.order_by('is_verified', '-created_on').values('is_verified', 'created_on')
<QuerySet [
    {'is_verified': False, 'created_on': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 26, 5, 24, 50, 117488},
    {'is_verified': False, 'created_on': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 26, 5, 10, 50, 117488},
    {'is_verified': True, 'created_on': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 26, 5, 55, 0, 599120},
    {'is_verified': True, 'created_on': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 26, 5, 21, 26, 632626}
]>```

Comment: That is weird, it should work according to documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: This is weird, This solution was not working yesterday. Now it's working fine. I don't know the cause of that issue. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to:

```
query_set_normal = query_set.filter(practice=False).order_by('-created_date')
```

Comment: I need the combined query_set of both practice and normal. The normal bookings should be in the order of "order_by('created_date')"

Comment: Do you still have problem after answer by... Subin?